# SQL request - search query not working

Tags: sql, search

In sql table i have fields: *name*, *description* and *language*

my language field has values like: "en-GB" or "fr-FR".

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE `name` LIKE '%yellow%' OR `description` LIKE '%yellow%' AND `language` = 'en-GB';
```

Results with search term **yellow** are ok. but i get also results who has langauge  *fr-FR*, but in my query i have set as language *en-GB*.

I have searched for query on [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp), and i think part with "like" is true.

What i do here wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paranthesis

```
SELECT * FROM items 
WHERE (`name` LIKE '%yellow%' OR `description` LIKE '%yellow%') AND `language` = 'en-GB';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use brackets as the 'OR' operated is evaluated first, where you are expecting the 'AND' operator to be.

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     items 
WHERE    (`name` LIKE '%yellow%' OR `description` LIKE '%yellow%') 
    AND  `language` = 'en-GB'
```

Answer (score 0):

get `language` to front of where

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE `language`='en-GB' AND (`name` LIKE '%yellow%' OR `description` LIKE '%yellow%');
```